# set parent entity property as primary key in child entity

Tags: c#, sql-server, ef-code-first

I'm working with Entity Framework Code First. `Student` is the child entity to `School`. I want the `Student` table to have a composite primary key: `SchoolID` and `StudentID`. My code currently only has `StudentID` as the primary key. EF automatically creates a foreign key `FK_dbo.Students_dbo.Schools_School_SchoolID`. How can I set this foreign key to also be part of the composite primary key? I'd prefer not adding new properties because `Student` and `School` are generated from large JSONs. The code below fails because `billGates` and `kofiAnnan` have the same primary key.

```
class School
{
    public School(int schoolID)
    {
        SchoolID = schoolID;
        Students = new List<Student>();
    }
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int SchoolID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}

class Student
{
    public Student(int studentID)
    {
        StudentID = studentID;
    }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
}

class EducationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public EducationDbContext() : base("name=SqlConnection") { }

    public DbSet<School> Schools { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var db = new EducationDbContext())
        {
            var harvard = new School(0);
            var billGates = new Student(3);
            harvard.Students.Add(billGates);
            db.Schools.Add(harvard);
            var mit = new School(1);
            var kofiAnnan = new Student(3);
            mit.Students.Add(kofiAnnan);
            db.Schools.Add(mit);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: The actual JSON I'm using below is one `match`. Each `match` has multiple `teams`. Each `team` has multiple `bans`. I'd like the `bans` table's primary key to be a composite of the `match` primary key `gameId` and the `team` primary key `teamId`.

https://pastebin.com/KBrXnt7Q

Comment: Why are you using the same StudentID for Bill and Kofi ?

Comment: Bill is the third student at Harvard and Kofi is the third student at MIT. They can be uniquely identified by the key `{ SchoolID, StudentID }`. Bill would be `{0, 3}`. Kofi would be `{1, 3}`.

Comment: I assume this is a homework. I would use another table/class Enrollment to keep associations between students and schools. Every enrollment should have a references to student (StudentID), school (SchoolID), year (?) and something like EnrolmentNumber (for example). Student should have unique IDs (unique StudentID).

Comment: If I use `Enrollment`, I still have the same problem because `Student`'s primary key of `3` is still shared by Bill and Kofi. If Harvard assigns Bill `3` and MIT assigns Kofi `3`, is there a way I can distinguish the two students in the `Student` table by way of their `SchoolID`?

Comment: "Student should have unique IDs (unique StudentID). "